# Add non-editable text after cursor in input box

Tags: jquery, html, css, cursor-position, inputbox

I'm trying to add non-editable text after the cursor in a text field/input box as to achieve the following:

1) The text before the cursor is editable
2) The text after the cursor is not editable and moves right/left as the text to the left is added/removed

INPUT FIELD: [editabletexthere{cursorhere}non-editabletexthere   ]

Here is the code to my input box thus far:

```
<input id="edit_input" type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" autofocus onfocus="this.value = this.value;" value="editabletext" style="width:100%;"></input>
```

I feel like the values in the input should be housed within a span and for the second span simply to be stylized with contenteditable= false;. I would also like to stylize the non-editable text to a different color. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can't split an input field in half.  Not sure what you are attempting to do with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might not be the best solution, it's kind of a hack but it works fine.
The idea is to create a div that looks like an input box with inside 2 span, and you make one of them editable.

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

span {
    width: auto;
    outline: 0;
}

span.trailing {
    color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span contenteditable="true" id="edit_input_fake">Input</span>
    <span class="trailing">Trailing text</span>
  </div>
```

You can create an `<input type="hidden">` where you copy the content of the first span (maybe the second one as well?) on event keydown/change if needed.

JSFiddle available here: http://jsfiddle.net/c6f7ommh/1

Comment: This looks good. One question: is there a way to get the cursor to be after the entered text? i.e. after the "Input"?

Comment: When the caret is at the end of the user entered text - it stops blinking - how do you maintain the blinking caret?

Comment: This behaves like a textarea not like an input, if I press enter then it gets higher

Answer (score 2):

### JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mxdqydpt/)

You could do it like this:

**HTML:**

```
<input id="edit_input" type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" autofocus onfocus="this.value = this.value;" value="editabletext" style="width:100%;"></input>
<p>SOME TEXT</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
input {
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0px 120px 0px 0px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
p {
    margin:0px 0px 0px -100px;
    float:left;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

**[EDITED]**

If you want to `cursor: default;` and `user-select: none;` - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mxdqydpt/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to inform your users that some text will be appended to whatever they are typing in when it is persisted, simply adding a label after the textbox with the non-editable portion is good enough. Your server code can then, in parallel, append the non-editable portion to the submitted text, since I assume it is a constant.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm still a little unsure about the line between comments and answers. Seems like this would solve OP's problem.